# C++: Applying an argument to range of functions

Tags: c++, function, arguments

Is there a some more standard way of applying an argument to range of functions? I came up with solutions like the one listed below, but it feels wrong - out there should be something already for building such logic.

```
template<typename Function, typename Result, typename Argument>
struct apply_argument_t {
    Argument x;
    Result operator () (Function f) {
        return f (x);
    }
};
```

Thus a simple use case:

```
transform (in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), apply_argument(x));
```

I intentionally skipped implementation details.

**Edit:** But anyway, as they were asked for:

`in` is a range of unary functions (e.g. `vector<int(*)(char)>`)

`out` is a range of these unary function's results (e.g. `vector<int>`)

`apply_argument` is like the structure but without the template specification and initialization (e.g. `apply_argument_t<int(*)(char), int, char>`)

Also I missed the remark that a solution for C++11 is not searched.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What is `in`, and `out`? What is `apply_argument` (an instance of the class template, but with what template arguments?)?

Answer (score 1):

> I intentionally skipped implementation details.

Well those details include where you got e.g. the `Argument` type from.

Anyway, use a lambda.

Comment: It's an element from range of unary functions, I also added some clarification - thanks for the remarks. I also commented that I don't search for C++11.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alf, but let's show you how to do that in your case.

Here is a possible solution to your problem with lambdas in case you use C++11:
(I use `Function` but you will need to use your own specific function type.)

```
Argument x;
transform (in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(),
  [x](Function f)
  {
    return f(x);
  }
);
```

Further reading on wikipedia, C++11.

Comment: Thank you, I added some clarification also (no C++11 though), thus in your example it will be more like inversed: `e(f)`, `f` will be an object passed to function `e` found in range `in`.

Comment: `auto` is not valid in function parameters, so until we have polymorphic lambdas something like `decltype(in)::reference` can be used (`const_reference` is also an option or is even mandatory if `in` is `const`-qualified).

Comment: @LucDanton: thx, I corrected it, sorry. You are right, he should supply his type at the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to use C++11, there is a different solution using `<functional>` from STL:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Argument, typename Result>
Result apply_function(Return (*f)(Argument), Argument x)
{
  return f(x);
}

transform (in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), bind2nd(ptr_fun(apply_function), x) );
```

But I think your solution is cleaner. I could think about only one possible simplification:

```
template<typename Argument, typename Result>
struct apply_argument_t {
    Argument x;
    Result operator () (Result (*f)(Argument)) {
        return f (x);
    }
};
```

---

There should be a solution **using Boost lambda library**, but [it does **not** work](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?Cookbook_-_Lambda_Library) for some reason:

```
#include<boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include<boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
using namespace boost::lambda;
transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), bind(_1, x));
```

[Reference also here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#id2476894) (I've tried everything, `protect`, too but they did not work.)

Comment: Placeholders don't easily work in the first position (that of the function), it's a much simpler design to simply not support that functionality, which is the case for all lazy evaluation libraries I know of.

Comment: Yes, but then the documentation should tell this explicitly. There is even an example on Boost page where the placeholder is in the first position: `bind(_1, a, b, c)(foo);`